# How to handle images from request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a dotnet API server and I want to send images in the request body, but when I make a request from postman I have an error "Unsupported Media Type"
[image: 1]

here is my API controller, I have changed the argument of the function from an object to a byte array but it does not help, what should I do to be able to send a request with a file in the body as binary to handle it
[image: 2]

Comment: what content type are you sending?

Comment: @derloopkat Content-Type: image/jpeg

Comment: you should send IFormFile.

Comment: @tmsbrndz I am a newbie, can you elaborate on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get file with `IFormFile`.

E.g:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostImage([FromForm] IFormFile image){
  if (image == null || image.Length == 0)
  {
     return BadRequest();
  }
  // Do something with image
}
```

Comment: Now I do not have an error about content type but the image is null

Comment: @AkezhanOb1 in postman your request's body needs to be form-data.

Comment: Yeah I know, I have already changed but still, the image is null

Comment: Parameter name (image) in controller and key at form-data needs to be same.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a trouble in the sending data, but you can read the request body content directly.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("image")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImageAsync() {
    using var buffer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    await this.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(buffer, this.Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    var imageBytes = buffer.ToArray();
    // process the image
    return NoContent();
}
```